# Silverlight: disable automatic first-row selection after DataGrid binding

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, paging, silverlight-toolkit, pagedcollectionview

I have a Silverlight `DataGrid`, a `DataPager` and a `PagedCollectionView`.
After the PagedCollection view is bound to the `DataGrid`, the first row of the `DataGrid` is selected.

This behaviour **does not happen,** if i am using an `ObservableCollection`. But due to the `DataPager`, I need to use the `PagedCollectionView`.

I am using Silverlight 5 RC, and the SL 4 Toolkit.

Example of Usage:

#### View:

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="gridSomeItems" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItems, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserSortColumns="True">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Column1}" />
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
<sdk:DataPager Source="{Binding Path=ItemsSource, ElementName=gridSomeItems}"/>
```

#### ViewModel:

```
public class SomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public SomeViewModel(IDataAccess dataAccess)
    {
        _dataAccess = dataAccess;
        _dataAccess.GetSomeItemsCompleted += GetSomeItemsCompleted;
        _dataAccess.GetSomeItems();           
    }

    public PagedCollectionView SomeItems { get; set; }
    public SomeItem SelectedItem { get; set; }

    private void GetSomeItemsCompleted(GetSomeItemsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        SomeItems = new PagedCollectionView(e.Result.SomeItems);         
        RaisePropertyChanged("SomeItems");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best workaround is to set a `_isLoading` flag. The following code would be the correct code for the ViewModel:

```
public class SomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _isLoading;

    public SomeViewModel(IDataAccess dataAccess)
    {
        _dataAccess = dataAccess;
        _dataAccess.GetSomeItemsCompleted += GetSomeItemsCompleted;
        _isLoading = true;
        _dataAccess.GetSomeItems();           
    }

    public PagedCollectionView SomeItems { get; set; }
    public SomeItem SelectedItem { get; set; }

    private void GetSomeItemsCompleted(GetSomeItemsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        SomeItems = new PagedCollectionView(e.Result.SomeItems);         
        SomeItems.CurrentChanged += CurrentItemChanged;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SomeItems");
        SomeItems.MoveCurrentTo(null);
        _isLoading = false;     
    }

    private void CurrentItemChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_isLoading)
        {
            SelectedItem = SomeItems.CurrentItem as SomeItem;
            // Do something more...
        }
    }   
}
```

Please have a look at the row `SomeItems.MoveCurrentTo(null);` - This command really sets the CurrentItem of the PagedCollectionView to null (not selected).

It is still a workaround... Would be great if anybody came up with a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why that is happening unless you are somehow setting the SelectedItem property in your code somehow.

A simple solution to the problem would be to use a Behavior on the DataGrid that sets the SelectedIndex to -1 when the loaded event fires.

Comment: Hm. That could be a workaround - but the SelectedItem does also change, when the DataPager moves to the next page. So i would have to catch this event too...

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is that you need to do something like:

```
private PagedCollectionView someItems;
public PagedCollectionView SomeItems
{
    get { return someItems; }

    set
    {
        if (someItems != value)
        {
            someItems = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SomeItems");
        }
    }
}
```

And implement that same strategy for `SelectedItem`.

Comment: Thats right, but I am fireing the RaisePropertyChanged in the Load-Completed event (if you have a Look on the method `GetSomeItemsCompleted`). The `SelectedItem` doesn't need to be raised, because this should only be set by the grid and not from the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the situation by putting the `MoveCurrentTo(null)` inside the PageIndexChanged event. Like that:

1. XAML

   ```
   <data:DataPager x:name="pager" PageIndexChanged="dataPagerGroup_PageIndexChanged" />
   ```
2. C#

   ```
   private void PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       (this.pager.Source as PagedCollectionView).MoveCurrentTo(null);
   }
   ```